# Pound(#) sign in web address

Tags: html, hyperlink, webaddress

i recently saw the usage of the pound(#) sign in web addresses. An example:
http://www.example.com/#/contact

My question is what the # role? How is this built?
Thank you in advance

Comment: see for `window.location.hash` in Javascript...

Comment: It is not a pound sign, it is a hash sign.

Comment: @piokuc - It is, depending on where you are from.

Comment: Searching Google for your exact title would haven given you the answer without typing out a question.

Comment: It's actually called an octothorpe.

Comment: @Oded Can you give an example of a country where # is a pound sign? In the UK pound sign is £

Comment: @piokuc From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sign) - "In American and Canadian English, the symbol usually called the pound sign describes instead the number sign #".

Comment: Well, apparently even Javascript calls it a hash... must be a sign that anyone calling it a pound sign is just wrong, was he a USA citizen or not...

Comment: @Oded Thanks, yeah, I just saw the Wikipedia page, too. The sentence you quoted is a bit weird, but I get the point. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi all,thanks for all your answers. I am sorry to have called the hash sign (#) a pound. I confused it. I knew about it's usage in links within a page but I haven't met this kind of construction before. i searched the web for it and found only references to internal links. After changing the terms I found out that is a procedure used by many sites to use ajax and it is called hashbang. Thanks again for your time.